# Busca CEP Correios

Tags: php

Estou tentando uma implementação em `php` via `simplexml_load_file` para verificação e retorno de dados junto à API dos Correios. Neste caso, é necessário passar variáveis na `url`. Estou fazendo assim:

Estou fazendo assim:

```
function encontraCep() {
      $cep = $_POST["txtCep"];

      $url = "https://apps.correios.com.br/SigepMasterJPA/AtendeClienteService/AtendeCliente?wsdl&txtCep=".$cep;      
      $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);


      return $xml;

  }

 dados = encontraCep();
```

um simples

```
 print "<pre>";
 print_r($dados);
 print "</pre>";
```

Me retorna:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [name] => AtendeClienteService
            [targetNamespace] => http://cliente.bean.master.sigep.bsb.correios.com.br/
        )

)
```

Onde estou errando?

Estou seguindo o tutorial dado em http://www.eduardorizo.com.br/2014/12/04/correios-webservice-para-consulta-de-enderecos-a-partir-de-um-cep/, feito em asp.net

Lá ele faz um form:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <h1>Teste WS dos Correios</h1><br />
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" GroupingText="Busca Endereço">
      CEP:
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtCep" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>&amp;nbsp;<asp:Button ID="btnBuscarEndereco" runat="server" OnClick="btnBuscarEndereco_Click" Text="Buscar Endereço" />
      <br />
      <asp:Label ID="lblEndereco" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </asp:Panel>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

E uma função que pega o retorno:

```
protected void btnBuscarEndereco_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  wsCorreio.AtendeClienteClient ws = new wsCorreio.AtendeClienteClient("AtendeClientePort"); //Verificar o nome do endpoint no arquivo Web.config
  var dados = ws.consultaCEP(txtCep.Text);
  if (dados != null)
  {
    lblEndereco.Text = string.Format(@"Endereço: {0}<br />
                       Complemento 1: {1}<br />
                       Complemento 2: {2}<br />
                       Bairro: {3}<br />
                       Cidade: {4}<br />
                       Estado: {5}",
                       dados.end,
                       dados.complemento,
                       dados.complemento2,
                       dados.bairro,
                       dados.cidade,
                       dados.uf);
  }
  else
    lblEndereco.Text = "CEP não encontrado.";
}
```

Mas não há `action` no `form` dele para vermos o envio da `url`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você tem utilizar no PHP o [SoapClient](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.soapclient.php) para carregar o [WSDL](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language) (Web Service) e utilizar suas funcionalidades.

No código logo abaixo você recupera as informações mediante o número do CEP.

```
<?php   

    $config = array(
        "trace" => 1, 
        "exception" => 0, 
        "cache_wsdl" => WSDL_CACHE_MEMORY
    );

    $address = 'https://apps.correios.com.br/SigepMasterJPA/AtendeClienteService/AtendeCliente?wsdl';   

    $client = new SoapClient($address, $config);

    $cep  = $client->consultaCEP(['cep' =>'01415000']);
```

**Resultado**

```
object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["return"]=> object(stdClass)#3 (8) 
{ ["bairro"]=> string(12) "Consolação" ["cep"]=> string(8) "01415000"
  ["cidade"]=> string(10) "São Paulo" ["complemento"]=> string(0) "" 
  ["complemento2"]=> string(21) "- até 586 - lado par" 
  ["end"]=> string(15) "Rua Bela Cintra" ["id"]=> int(0) 
  ["uf"]=> string(2) "SP" } 
}
```

**Sequencia:**

```
$config: configurações do serviço

$address: endereço do WSDL

$client: instância da classe SoapClient com as configurações e endereço

$cliente->consultaCEP: é a função que recupera as informações do CEP informado
```

**Observações:**

1) No *consultaCEP* para funciona é um Array no formato `[cep => 'numero do cep']`

2) **Esse WebService é muito lento!**

---

**CEP inválido e Erros:**

Use assim:

```
try
{
    $cep  = $client->consultaCEP(['cep' =>'11111111']);
    var_dump($cep);
}
catch(Exception $e) 
{
    var_dump($e);
}
```

> object(SoapFault)#3 (10) { ["message":protected]=> string(18) "CEP NAO
>   ENCONTRADO" ["string":"Exception":private]=> string(0) ""
>   ["code":protected]=> int(0) ["file":protected]=> string(26)
>   "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\cep.php" ["line":protected]=> int(16)
>   ["trace":"Exception":private]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(6) { ["file"]=>
>   string(26) "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\cep.php" ["line"]=> int(16)
>   ["function"]=> string(6) "__call" ["class"]=> string(10) "SoapClient"
>   ["type"]=> string(2) "->" ["args"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(11)
>   "consultaCEP" [1](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.soapclient.php)=> array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["cep"]=> string(8)
>   "11111111" } } } } } ["previous":"Exception":private]=> NULL
>   ["faultstring"]=> string(18) "CEP NAO ENCONTRADO" ["faultcode"]=>
>   string(11) "soap:Server" ["detail"]=> object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
>   ["SigepClienteException"]=> string(18) "CEP NAO ENCONTRADO" } }

Você pode então verificar se não retornou nada!

**Alternativas prontas de pacotes em PHP no Site** [PackagistThe PHP Package Repository](https://packagist.org/)

1 - [zizaco/cep-consult](https://packagist.org/packages/zizaco/cep-consult) pelo site dos correios

2 - [canducci/cep](https://packagist.org/packages/canducci/cep) pelo site viacep.com.br

3 - [cagartner/correios-consulta](https://packagist.org/packages/cagartner/correios-consulta) tem até cálculo de frete

Comment: erro nesta linha: $cep  = $client->consultaCEP(['cep' =>'01415000']);

Comment: qual erro? @CarlosRocha

Comment: Arrumei asim  $cepC = array ('cep'=>'36880000');   $cep  = $client->consultaCEP($cepC);. Mas me diz 2 coisas: esse retorna não informa códigos de erro? Poque você diz que esse web service é muito lento? Você usa outro? Na verdade, o que ocorre é que na loja, assim que o cliente coloca o cep, ele vai para uma página de formulário de endereço, e depois é que ele vai para página de calculo do frete. Não estou encontrando um webservice que retorna preço e prazo e também os dados do endereço

Comment: Deve ser a versão do seu php por isso do erro, mas já arrumo blz. Se o cep não for encontrada ele informa sim digite um cep invalido. O webservice demora pra responder no PHP já no .Net é normal isso eu não sei dizer e sim os correios. Eu uso o (viacep.com.br)[viacep.com.br]

Comment: Mas não retorna código de erro essa requisição. Ao invés disso, dá erro no SOAP. É isso mesmo?

Comment: Outra coisa: viacep é seguro?

Comment: O ***viacep.com.br*** é uma alternativa que nunca me deixou na mão. Fiz uma edição na resposta, observer e utilize da melhor maneira possivel.

Comment: muito obrigado. Muito obrigado mesmo!

Comment: parou de funcionar esse script. Adiciona na tua resposta a implementação vi cep fazendo favor

Comment: adicionei em outra resposta!

Answer (score 2):

Tem um exemplo em PHP para isso, inclusive eu já usei, acesse http://www.rafaelwendel.com/2012/08/preenchimento-automatico-do-endereco-a-partir-do-cep/. Na Url que utiliza em seu exemplo não me retorna nada ,ele utiliza a url http://cep.republicavirtual.com.br/web_cep.php?formato=xml&cep= que você pode até testar em seu navegador que dá certo, basta passar o cep.

Como pode ver no exemplo é só chamar a url e trabalhar com o retorno:

```
<?php

$cep = $_POST['cep'];

$reg = simplexml_load_file("http://cep.republicavirtual.com.br/web_cep.php?formato=xml&cep=" . $cep);

$dados['sucesso'] = (string) $reg->resultado;
$dados['rua']     = (string) $reg->tipo_logradouro . ' ' . $reg->logradouro;
$dados['bairro']  = (string) $reg->bairro;
$dados['cidade']  = (string) $reg->cidade;
$dados['estado']  = (string) $reg->uf;

echo json_encode($dados);

?>
```

Comment: Pois é. Mas a url que uso é dos correios, e essa é da republica virtual. Não corre risco de isso estar desatualizado? Porque depois de verificar o cep, preciso calcular o preço do frete na api dos correios. Se a base de dados não for a mesma, então pode ser que eu tenha problemas.

Answer (score 0):

Outra forma é pelo site do [viacep.com.br](https://viacep.com.br/)

***Código:***

```
<?php   

    function webClient ($url)
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $data;
    }
    $cep = "01414000";
    $url = sprintf('http://viacep.com.br/ws/%s/json/ ', $cep);
    $result = json_decode(webClient($url));

    var_dump($result);
```

***Resultado:***

```
object(stdClass)#1 (9) { 
 ["cep"]=> string(9) "01414-000" 
 ["logradouro"]=> string(16) "Rua Haddock Lobo" 
 ["complemento"]=> string(20) "até 1048 - lado par" 
 ["bairro"]=> string(16) "Cerqueira César" 
 ["localidade"]=> string(10) "São Paulo" 
 ["uf"]=> string(2) "SP" 
 ["unidade"]=> string(0) "" 
 ["ibge"]=> string(7) "3550308" 
 ["gia"]=> string(4) "1004" }
```

***Como usar:***

```
echo $result->cep;
echo $result->logradouro;
echo $result->complemento;
echo $result->bairro;
echo $result->localidade;
echo $result->uf;
echo $result->unidade;
echo $result->ibge;
echo $result->gia;
```